# How to validate a single field name with different DTO types by conditions in nest.js

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs, dto

I have a same field name in a DTO, but that field has different DTO types according to conditions. It is a bit hard to understand in words, but you can see clearly when you see the code.

```
export class EmailTypeDto {
  @IsEnum(EmailType)
  public type: EmailType;

  @ValidateIf((o) => o.type === EmailType.ACCOUNT_SUCCESS)
  @Type(() => AccountSuccessDto)
  @ValidateNested()
  postData: AccountSuccessDto;

  @ValidateIf((o) => o.type === EmailType.MAIN_INQUIRY)
  @Type(() => MainInquiryDto)
  @ValidateNested()
  postData: MainInquiryDto;
}
```

I get error that postData cannot be duplicated.
The postData field name is always the same, but the value of postData is different according to email type, and those different fields are determined in each email type dtos.

This is the code I tried, which obviously did not work.
I tried @ValidatorConstraint, but cannot find a way.
It kind of looks like this, but no.

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'EmailTypeValidation', async: true })
export class EmailTypeValidation implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  async validate(postData: object, args: ValidationArguments) {
    switch (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args.object)).type) {
      case EmailType.TEST:
        postData = AccountSuccessDto;
        return true;
      case EmailType.MAIN_INQUIRY:
        postData = MainInquiryDto;
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding or changing parameters for @Type and @ValidateIf, but also no.

Answer (score 1):

Following the error you received - `EmailTypeDto` class cannot contain 2 properties of the same name.

Hence, you should use union type for `postData` property, alogn with the `@Validate` decorator using for your custom validation class:

```
import { IsEnum, IsNotEmpty, Validate} from "class-validator";


export class EmailTypeDto {
  @IsEnum(EmailType)
  public type: EmailType;

  @Validate(EmailTypeValidation)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  postData: AccountSuccessDto | MainInquiryDto;
```

In your custom validation class `EmailTypeValidation` you should only check if the type is one of the required types:

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'EmailTypeValidation', async: true })
export class EmailTypeValidation implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  async validate(postData: object, args: ValidationArguments) {
    switch (args.object['type']) {
      case EmailType.ACCOUNT_SUCCESS:
      case EmailType.MAIN_INQUIRY:
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```